# Proyecto webLogic falla con NullPointerException at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.SchemaGenerator.addSchemaComponents

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

estoy intentando desplegar un proyecto en weblogic pero no me deja, me sale el siguiente error en el log

> [2020-07-28T15:30:53.389-05:00] [AdminServer] [WARNING] []
> [com.sun.xml.ws.server.http] [tid: [STANDBY].ExecuteThread: '40' for
> queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: ]
> [ecid: 375292d1-adc7-4cb9-aeaa-d8702037fdd9-00000035,0] [APP: merc]
> [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] Ignoring wrong
> wsdl=/WEB-INF/wsdl/IndiceDinamicoService/IndiceDinamicoServiceV1.wsdl.
> It should start with WEB-INF/wsdl. Going to generate and publish a new
> WSDL. [2020-07-28T15:30:53.719-05:00] [AdminServer] [ERROR] []
> [com.sun.xml.ws.server.http] [tid: [STANDBY].ExecuteThread: '40' for
> queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: ]
> [ecid: 375292d1-adc7-4cb9-aeaa-d8702037fdd9-00000035,0] [APP:
> mercurioEPM] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL]
> WSSERVLET11: Fallo al analizar el descriptor en tiempo de ejecución:
> java.lang.NullPointerException[[ java.lang.NullPointerException   at
> org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.SchemaGenerator.addSchemaComponents(SchemaGenerator.java:352)

ya verifique si existe el archivo IndiceDinamicoServiceV1.wsdl y si existe tanto el java como el wsdl que podría ser?

Comment: En la traza dice `It should start with WEB-INF/wsdl.`. Seguro que las rutas están bien en tu proyecto?

Comment: si bro pues en la carpeta wsdl hay otras carpetas y entre ellas esta IndiceDinamicoService que es donde esta el archivo pero no se si tenga que estar el archivo afuera en la carpeta wsdl nada mas

Answer (score 0):

El error es muy claro y te lo indica correctamente.

Ignoring wrong wsdl=   /WEB-INF/wsdl/IndiceDinamicoService/IndiceDinamicoServiceV1.wsdl.

It should start with WEB-INF/wsdl.

Es decir, el wsdl no está en /WEB-INF sino dentro de weblogic WEB-INF/. Le estas indicando a weblogic que busque en el /, donde está /boot, /var /opt /etc /tmp etc...  en lugar de dentro de su estructura interna de directorios.

Comment: y como le indico que busque en /Web-INF?

Comment: Siento el retraso en responder. Sin poder ver el código de la aplicación java o los descriptores (ficheros xml) no podría saber donde está ese error. Pero ten por seguro que en algún sitio hay una ruta que especifica claramente donde está el WEB-INF y está mal.

Comment: si exactamente era por que webLogic me generaba problemas con u servicio REST